# Exclude Package From Gradle Dependency

Tags: java, web-services, rest, gradle

I'm experiencing an issue where multiple versions of the same class are showing up in my classpath.  The class in question is `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`.  The version I want to use is brought in by `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1`. However, we also use the Jira rest client library which has a dependency on the older version of jersey (`com.sun.jersey:jersey-core`) which has included the java.ws packages bundled in it's jar.

Here is an example snippet from the build file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:2.0.0-m31'
  compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'
  compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.17'
}
```

I can't remove `com.sun.jersey:jersey-core` as it uses different package name from the new version and would cause class def not found exceptions in the Jira client.

As far as I can tell, my options at this point are:

1. Revert to using Jersey 1.x and it's implementation of jsr311
2. Somehow have gradle exclude the `javax.ws` package from the old jersey client.

I'd like to keep using the newer version of jersey so #2 would be my ideal solution but I'm not sure if it's even possible.  Does anyone know how to go about this?  If that's not possible, I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19 doesn't bundle the javax.ws.rs class files and instead lists them as a compile-time dependency.  Adding this snippet to my build.gradle fixed the issue.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    // For a version that doesn't package javax.ws
    force 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19' 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can exclude an transitive dependency module like this:

```
   compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.17') {
      exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs'
      exclude module: 'javax.ws.rs-api'
   }
```

ref: [50.4.7 here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Comment: The problem is that javax isn't a transitive dependency, it's included in the the com.sun.jersey:jersey-core jar.  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.17  See the javax.ws packages in the packages section.

Comment: isn't http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.17 this what you're adding as dependency in your question? javax.wx.rs is a dependency here.

Comment: Yes I'm adding org.glassfish.jersey.core but Jira brings in con.sun.jersey which has javax.ws.rs included in it's jar.

Comment: Do we have a stuff for adding extra dependencies to a dependency? (like 'include 'com.example.other.library'')

Answer (score 0):

exclude the group and module as below.

Ex :

```
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13') {
    exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
}
```