# Excluding classes with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I'm pulling in a rather large library to a project I'm working on (which is massive as well). I've had a large number of dependency conflicts but I'm strangely stuck on this one.

The error in question is this one:

```
Error:Program type already present: org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS
```

How does one go about determining where the depedency conflict lies, and how do you exlude this? In the past I've been able to just exclude whole modules but I don't know how to determine what module this class belongs to. Could I use exclude group instead of exclude module? How does that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate? Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942825/exclude-package-from-gradle-dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Package From Gradle Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942825/exclude-package-from-gradle-dependency)