# Excluding troublesome classes in Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I'm using gradle to pull in a dependency and see the following proguard issue. I've tried the answer here

[Exclude Package From Gradle Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942825/exclude-package-from-gradle-dependency)

But it appears to not work.

The proguard manual talks about this warning "Warning: library class ... depends on program class ..." and has this to say about Android specifically.

"In Android development, sloppy libraries may contain duplicates of classes that are already present in the Android runtime (notably org.w3c.dom, org.xml.sax, org.xmlpull.v1, org.apache.commons.logging.Log, org.apache.http, and org.json). You must remove these classes from your libraries, since they are possibly inconsistent, and the runtime libraries would get precedence anyway."

How do you remove these classes from your libraries? Bonus question: what defines the difference between a library and program class and what did these libraries do to cause these issues?