# How do I exclude a package using Gradle configuration only in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Similar to [Exclude Package From Gradle Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942825/exclude-package-from-gradle-dependency) but I am specifically asking for IntelliJ only so it will not be suggested by any auto complete.

So I still need it to be present when it is building the package.

Is such a configuration possible?

What I want to avoid is the situation where a shaded jar gets suggested for import instead of the real one.

Comment: It's not possible via Gradle as it's an IDE level setting: Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from auto-import and completion.

Comment: OK thx I was hoping it was configurable using the `idea` plugin